# AngularJS - Editing an object and applying / reverting changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table of items with an edit button next to it. When the edit button is clicked, the fields in that row turn into input fields where they can be edited, and a cancel button shows up. If they click cancel, the fields turn back into regular display fields. It's kind of like inline editing. I have two sets of `<td>` elements: one for display and one for editing.

What I'm looking for is a good way for me to keep the item's original values, so that when they click cancel, the data goes back to what it was originally. But if they click save, I'd like that data to stay on the object and that's what should be displayed.

I originally tried this (logic and processing is in the controller): On the edit button click, I'd create a "snapshot" of the object as an attribute on itself. Something like...

```
vm.edit = function(item) {
    item.modified = angular.copy(item);
}
```

So what I'm actually doing is, when the row is not being edited, I'm displaying `item.someProperty`. When the edit button is clicked, it performs that copy in the controller, and the fields I show are actually `item.modified.someProperty`. Those are the different bindings in those two sets of `<td>` elements I mentioned, aside from the fact that the second set are input fields.

It works well as far as reverting goes (when they click cancel), but I'm stuck at the part where I want to update the object's original values if they click save. Basically, I need a way to get `item.modified` properties onto `item` itself. I've tried doing something like:

```
vm.save = function(item) {
    item = angular.copy(item.modified);
}
```

And it doesn't seem to be working. I don't think I expected it to work in the first place, because it's kind of like overwriting itself with itself. Not sure if that would work.

What is a good way to accomplish this? Or maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I guess more clear will be rewrite

`vm.save = function(item) {
    var copy = angular.copy(item.modified);
   item = copy;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `copy()` and `extend()`. Only edit the copy and store a reference to original that you can extend when you save

```
var  storedItem;


// copy to variable before editing and store reference to original
vm.edit = function(item) {
    storedItem = item;
    vm.editItem = angular.copy(item);
}

vm.save = function() {
   angular.extend(storedItem, editItem);
   vm.editItem = null;
   storedItem = null;
}
```

Set various `ng-model`  to `vm.editItem` properties. If user cancels edit the original object has been unchanged so there is nothing to revert